# failed to find Vite server URL while running front end of apache age viewer Desktop (Go)

Tags: apache-age, wails

I'm trying to run front end of the [Age-viewer-go](https://github.com/apache/age/tree/ageviewer_go)

on ubuntu 22.04

using the `wails dev` command in age-viewer folder of the project.

but it gives the following error as shown in the image

`failed to find the Vite server URL`

[image: image showing error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error, you can try the following troubleshooting steps:

1. First of all, ensure that **Vite** is correctly installed. In your terminal, run:

```
npx vite --version 
OR 
yarn vite --version
```

2. Start the server manually. Run (from the root of your directory:

```
npm vite 
OR 
yarn vite
```

This should start the server and print its URL.

3. Check your configuration in `wails.json` to ensure that frontend corresponds to correct Vite URL and port.
4. Ensure that port is available. Check using:

```
lsof -i tcp:<port_number>
```

- If any of the above doesn't work, try rebuilding your project by deleting and reinstalling `node_modules`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, from the `age-viewer/frontend` directory run `npm install react-router-dom`.

The issue could be due to vite server port assignment.
For that try using a custom port for vite:

- Go to `age\age-viewer\frontend\vite.config.js`
- add

  ```
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
     port: 8000,
  }
  ```

The error could also be due to some problem with the frontend because after compiling the frontend wails is running `npm run dev` from the `wails.json`. Try running the frontend separately to test if it is working correctly.

To do that run:

- `cd age-viewer/frontend`
- `npm run dev`